# TeamCity: Gerrit plugin configuration

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity, gerrit

I have setup TeamCity to run build and tests on each git push and update verification result in the corresponding gerrit review. Everything works fine except for the URL that teamcity adds to the gerrit comment. The URL in question is the URL to the build that teamcity just ran and the host in the URL is set as localhost instead of the machine's hostname.

For example the comment that teamcity posts as part of gerrit verification looks like this

TeamCity has posted comments on this change.

```
Change subject: Commit message here
......................................................................


Patch Set 1: Verified+1

http://localhost:8111/viewLog.html?buildId....
```

Instead of localhost in the above URL, I want teamcity to use the proper hostname.

Where do I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config item is named serverUrl and present in `$TEAMCITY_HOME/buildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties`.